# PERL: Script Not Completing

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

I've had this script for just over two years now and never any issues up until two weeks ago and I've no idea why it's suddenly stopped completing.

Everyday the server downloads and unpacks a large xml file (109,000 records on average all formed like the example below.) which the script then takes and transfers from the xml file to a mysql database for storage and easier queries.

```
<ACCOUNT>
 <NAME>Name</NAME>
 <TYPE>Pretitle</TYPE>
 <FULLNAME>Fullname</FULLNAME>
 <MOTTO>Motto</MOTTO>
 <CATEGORY>Account Category</CATEGORY>
</ACCOUNT>
```

As I said, I've had no issues with it for over two years but for the past two weeks it stops after 68,000 (on average more or less) records have been transferred and I'd really like to know why. This is a straight transfer and I've confirmed that there are more than 68,000 records found within the xml file.

Here's the script in question. If anyone can verify that either this is a solid script or that it has issues I'd very much appreciate it. I'm at a complete loss.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
use strict;
use DBI;
use XML::Parser;
my %row = ("NAME" => undef, "TYPE" => undef, "FULLNAME" => undef, "MOTTO" => undef, "CATEGORY" => undef);
my $dbh = DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:database:localhost", "username", "password",
                       { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0});
my $parser = new XML::Parser (
                       Handlers => {
                           Start => \&handle_start,
                           End   => \&handle_end,
                           Char  => \&handle_text
                       }
                   );
$parser->parsefile ("accounts.xml");
$dbh->disconnect ();
sub handle_start
{
my ($p, $tag) = @_;   
   if ($tag eq "ACCOUNT")
   {
       foreach my $key (keys (%row))
       {
           $row{$key} = undef;
       }
   }
}

sub handle_text
{
my ($p, $data) = @_;      
   my $tag = $p->current_element ();
   $row{$tag} .= $data if exists ($row{$tag});
}

sub handle_end
{
my ($p, $tag) = @_;  
   if ($tag eq "ACCOUNT")
   {
       my $str;
       foreach my $key (keys (%row))
       {
           $str .= "," if $str;
           $str .= "$key=" . $dbh->quote($row{$key});
       }
       $dbh->do ("INSERT INTO TABLE SET $str");
   }
}
```

Comment: Error message? Exit code?

Comment: Why is this outputting a HTTP header?

Comment: I don't get any indicator that anything is wrong other than the records don't add up. Running it in the browser just timesout with a 500 error which you'd expect from running a script  in the browser that takes up to 20 minutes to complete. Once in a while I do run the script manually though not that often.
 
The HTTP header has been in the code for years and it's my understanding that it's needed in order to run the script from the browser. There hasn't been any issues from it being there.

Comment: I'm not sure "Once in a while" counts as sufficient now that you have a problem. Have you tried running the script manually against the current incoming data which causes the problem? If so, is there any indication of failure? How, specifically, have you confirmed that the incoming data has over 68000 records starting <ACCOUNT> and ending </ACCOUNT>?

Comment: The line `$row{$key} = undef` is a little suspect, although it shouldn't cause the problem you describe. You should replace it, together with the `foreach` loop that contains it, with just `%row = ()`.

Comment: Yes, several times I've ran the script manually over the past three days and all that appears in the browser after a few minutes is the 500 Internal Server Error. The script keeps adding records past this which I confirm by refreshing the table in phpMyAdmin. The records always stop around that 68,000 mark. I have also opened each new xml file in my editor and had the program find and replace each instance of <ACCOUNT> with <ACCOUNT1>. Once complete, the program returns 109,000 instances changed.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that 1) the xml is not good for the program at "that 68,000 mark" 2) error / exception handling is non existent

Comment: I'm curious, that since the script is processing over half of the records does this indicate the server is under stress perhaps? I'm grasping. I thought XML::Parser read from the file one record at a time instead of trying to load everything into its own object? If I have that right. I should mention that the database table has been built to correspond directly to the xml file with matching columns NAME, TYPE, FULLNAME, MOTTO, CATEGORY. I'm unsure how to modify the script to eliminate $row{$key} = undef because of this.

Comment: You need to check your web server error log file first. It seams like your script have run timeout.

Comment: Your web server config should include location of error log file. That should include the error condition text that you would see on the command line. Or you could run the script from the command line. Have you considered setting up a separate version where you could run these tests - it looks like all you would need is a local MySQL db, and having a dev copy of a system is normal practice to debug and test production systems.

Comment: @Borodin:  The `$row{$key} = undef` seems to be necessary for the next handler function, which only appends data if the key already exists.  You might instead consider putting a different sort of constructor here, such as:  %row = ( NAME => "", TYPE => "", FULLNAME => "", MOTTO => "", CATEGORY => "" ).  Otherwise, if the XML has a key you _don't_ expect, the current code doesn't exclude it from the structure, and the database might get cranky at that.  (Also, what happens if a field you expect is missing?)

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that does the insert in an "eval { };" section. Then print out $@ at the end of your script.

This will a) mean the exception is caught and the script can finish ( most likely without the row in question ) and b) you can see from the contents of $@ what is upsetting your script.